# Parallelization of many Map/Reduce jobs in mongoDB performance

Tags: multithreading, performance, mongodb, mapreduce

I have to execute an operation that launches a lot of Map/Reduce (~400) but every Map/Reduce is on a different collection, so it can't be any concurrent write.

To improve the performance of this operation I paralyzed it by creating a thread on application side (I use the Java driver) for each Map/Reduce (note that I don't use sharding mode).

But when I compared the results I ended up with some worst results that with a sequential execution (mono-thread).
To be more precise : 341 sec for sequential execution, 904 for a distributed one.
So instead of getting better execution time, it's three time longer.

Someone knows why mongoDB don't like parallelization of Map/Reduce processes ?

I found an article about it ([link](http://www.quora.com/MongoDB/Can-two-MapReduce-jobs-run-concurrently-on-a-mongod-process)), but now that mongoDB use the V8 engine I thought that should be ok.

Comment: How exactly did you create a thread per map reduce? As far as I know MongoDB will handle this stuff itself so I am unsure how you was able to make a thread per isolate

Comment: Yes sorry, I edited my post. I was talking of the application side. It's just that I don't wait the execution of the first map/reduce to launch the command of the others, so all the map/reduce are queried at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

First, do Map/Reduces at different databases, there was lock for per database(now at version 2.6).
Second, need more RAM and more faster disk IO, there may be the bottleneck.

Here is an example about how to use multi-core. http://edgystuff.tumblr.com/post/54709368492/how-to-speed-up-mongodb-map-reduce-by-20x
"The issue is that there is too much lock contention between the threads. MR is not very altruistic when locking (it yields every 1000 reads), and since MR jobs does a lot of writing too, threads end up waiting on each other. Since MongoDB has individual locks per database"